# Get most retweeted tweets of an account

Tags: twitter

Given a Twitter account, say [RealCarrotFacts](https://twitter.com/RealCarrotFacts), how can I order its tweets decreasing by number of retweets?

Comment: Are you willing to use the API to do it, or are you specifically looking for an application that will do it?

Comment: None of these answers take into account tweets which are straight (not quoted) retweets from other accounts - and considering the number of retweets the original tweet got - which is what Twitter shows as the number of retweets when you look at a direct retweet. Now of course this may not always be what you want, but it's what I want for my use-case. Any tools that do this or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 4):

If you are reticent to use the twitter API which includes [Tweets as platform objects](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) which have **retweet_count** as fields/attributes(e.g. `"retweet_count":1585` )there are tools that allow you to look at the most retweeted posts for a given account.

[My Top Tweet](http://mytoptweet.com/) will show you the top ten most retweeted posts from your own account.

[TweetReach Pro](http://tweetreach.com/products/pro) allows you to sort tweets in your 'Tracker' by most retweeted.

[Retweet count for specific tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427147/retweet-count-for-specific-tweet) is a thread in SO which discusses how to deal with this in R

Answer (score 3):

[Favstar](http://favstar.fm/users/RealCarrotFacts/most_retweeted) should do it. Not sure how up-to-date they are with accounts that haven't authorised them. (I think accounts that do are scanned first, but presumably they try to include data for all users.)

Answer (score 1):

Pop your handle into Social Bearing's Twitter Handle Search: [Found Here](https://socialbearing.com/search/user). A dashboard should come up with all their tweets.

[image]
Click on the button which say's "Sort tweets by..." and Select "Retweets (high to low)"

You can similarly use this method to find any of the following

- Items by order of retweets
- Items by order of favorites
- Items by order of engagement
- Items by order of sentiment

**This method works for any public twitter handle for up to 3200 tweets.**