# Find the most liked tweet from an account

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to find the most liked tweet from a public Twitter account? For example, what is the most liked [@StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow) tweet?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Pop your handle into Social Bearing's Twitter Handle Search: [Found Here](https://socialbearing.com/search/user). A dashboard should come up with all their tweets.

[image]
Click on the button which say's "Sort tweets by..." and Select "Favourites (high to low)"

You can similarly use this method to find any of the following

- Items by order of retweets
- Items by order of favorites
- Items by order of engagement
- Items by order of sentiment

**This method works for any public twitter handle for up to 3200 tweets.**

Comment: That worked perfectly! You may want to cross-post this answer to "[Get most retweeted tweets of a account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43538/get-most-retweeted-tweets-of-a-account)", as the accepted answer only works for accounts the user owns.

Comment: Alternatively, I could modify this question into the more general "Find the most liked/retweeted tweet on an account"

Comment: I have cross-posted the answer to the thread you mentioned, but I agree these two threads should be merged, but we will need to wait for an administrator to come online to do so.

Comment: It's not really the same question, it just turns out to have the same answer.  I think having the answer on both is okay, but in general, if they are in fact duplicates, please mark them as such.

Comment: The sorting applies only to the tweets currently loaded in view (which are the latest 200 by default). So before sorting, one must do "load more" at the end of the page several times (up to 16).

Comment: This no longer works well as the Twitter API limits it to the tweets from the past week.

Answer (score 20):

You can find the most favorited tweet but it needs a couple steps:

1. Use the search operator `min_faves` and a guess for what a high
   number of favorites would be.
   https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Astackoverflow%20min_faves%3A500&src=typed_query
2. Increase or decrease the number until there are only a few results,
   and then you'll see the answer.
3. In this case, https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Astackoverflow%20min_faves%3A1500&src=typed_query shows the most favorited tweet.
4. https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Astackoverflow%20min_retweets%3A2000&src=typed_query shows the most retweeted.

Comment: works for min_faves, thank you. but min_retweets is not working correctly. my tweet with 157 tweets shows up if I search for min_retweets:30 but it doesn't when I search with min_retweets:50.

Comment: This may be subject to the same 3,200 tweet limit as the other method. I ran a search against my account and it skipped a tweet that was a month older than the last result, and I have 11.5K total tweets. The Stack Overflow example returns much older tweets, but their total tweet count is only 3,146.