# Find Twitter account mostly retweeting and liking

Tags: twitter, twitter-api, twitter-integration, twitter-search, twitterfeed

There are multiple platforms that provide information like most mentioned, favourite tweet, most liked tweet, etc.

Is there any way to identify a Twitter account who is retweeting or liking the most content from another Twitter account?
I have gone through this question already: 
[Find the most liked tweet from an account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105958/find-the-most-liked-tweet-from-an-account) and other tools like twitonomy.con or foller.me.